# Shiny/Leaflet adding popups layerid is unused

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I am building an app based on the [superZip](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/superzip-example.html) example in Shiny. I am trying to get the popups to display but I get the error "is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL' Warning: Error in addPopups: unused argument (layerid = pctcd)

Here is the code, any assistance will be most helpful.

```
   observe({
    leafletProxy("map") %>% clearPopups()
    event <- input$map_shape_click
    if (is.null(event))
      return()
    print(event)

    pctcd <- as.vector(sp_azvtd$pctcd)


    showPrecinctPopup <- function(pctcd, lat, lng) {
      selectedPct <- sp_azvtd[sp_azvtd$pctcd == pctcd,]
      content <- paste0("<h4>",selectedPct$precinctna, "</h4>",  tags$br())
      leafletProxy("map") %>% addPopups(lng, lat, content, layerID = pctcd)

    }


    isolate({
      showPrecinctPopup(event$id, event$lat, event$lng)
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

syntax issue. layerID is layerId in leaflet. I still can't get the ID to pass to the event though.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is pctcd being a vector. So I would recommend you to try and change `pctcd <- as.vector(sp_azvtd$pctcd)` to `pctcd <- as.character(sp_azvtd$pctcd)` or `pctcd <- as.factor(sp_azvtd$pctcd)`

Comment: That was it. Thanks. This has been driving me crazy for almost a week. I need to brush up on my r data types. :)

Comment: @Garrett if you find the answer useful please accept and vote. Thanks :)